# Android Spinner Dropdown arrow not displaying

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment, spinner

my background for my fragment is white, and the arrow for the spinner does not display unless I click on it.

This is the snippet from my Java file:

```
    spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.accounts,R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("Select an account");
```

This is my XMLfor the spinner_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="inherit"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
android:textColor="#ff252525"/>
```

And this is my layout for my spinner_dropdown_items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="inherit"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
android:textColor="#ff252525"/>
```

This is how my spinner looks with a white background to my fragment: 
[White Colour Background - Spinner](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2nvrfk2sth6327/Screenshot_2015-03-10-13-27-34-1.png?dl=0)
And this is how it looks when I change my background colour to purple: 
[Purple background - Spinner](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hlf1i64xrsyc4u8/Screenshot_2015-03-10-13-27-46-1.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This works for me, much simpler as well:

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

And in your class file:

```
spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 30):

Try this one:

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinnPhoneTypes"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/thirtyFive"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/shape_drop_down_normal"
     android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

shape_drop_down_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#6f94c7" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/drop_arrow" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How do I go about doing this ? I am not too sure how I try this way

Comment: just an addition: if your drop_arrow is a vector, you have to change the `<item><bitmap..` part to `<item android:gravity="end" android:drawable="@drawable/drop_arrow" />`

Answer (score 24):

Check if you are giving a background for your `Spinner` and if you do remove it and it will solve the issue

Comment: What if I have to give a background color and keep the arrow?
For e this answer work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56263841/2768515

Answer (score 11):

Just add theme in `Spinner` tag and you are good to go.

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: woo! it's work for me

Answer (score 3):

To avoid using a drawable, wrap the spinner in a view and set a background color to the wrapper view. For example,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_bg">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/railayregular"
                app:adapter="@{adapter}"
                android:onItemSelected="@{click::click}"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is Set background image (with arrow) instead of color.

```
 spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_img);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this way but then the picture goes all over the spinner. I want the arrow to go at the side of the spinner. So at the minute it look like this ; [https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe59pxiehktwdet/Screenshot_2015-03-12-15-10-42-1.png?dl=0]

Answer (score 0):

remove background color for your spinner like may be you have set white background which will not display drop down icon

Answer (score 0):

This is also working for me If you are using Material Components as Theme,

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
      android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

And in your code:

```
spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_data, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding background color or resource. Change it

> foreground

instead of

> background

Example (Wrong):

```html
<Spinner
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/shape_yellow_bordered"
android:fontFamily="@font/palanquin_regular"
android:inputType="text" />
```

Example (True):

```html
<Spinner
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:foreground="@drawable/shape_yellow_bordered"
android:fontFamily="@font/palanquin_regular"
android:inputType="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add below into style.                  
    
        <style name="Spinner" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
            <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:pointerIcon" tools:targetApi="n">arrow</item>
            <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
        </style>
    
                  
        <Spinner
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_30"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3" />
    
        
        In the code
            
        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),
                R.layout.spinner_item, list3);
        //set the view for the Drop down list
        dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
        spinner3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);                          
    
    
        spinner_item.xml        
        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


A custom spinner layout and pointer icon is the trick. Also Don't use background on Spinner view.
```

This is how it would look.
[image]